# Calling functions from a module using a keyboard-input - "security risk"?

Tags: python, pyserial

I am currently trying to 'talk' to a serial device, I know what I have to send but do not know what it means. I want to use trial-and-error by calling each command as a function and wait for the response. Each command is defined like

```
def Testcommand1():
    if serial.isOpen() == True:
        serial.write(b'\x1d\x10\xff')
        print('Testcommand1 to do some specific stuff sent, awaiting response.')
    else:
        print('ERROR: Serial port is closed')
```

The following lines, which I am not including here, tell my computer to listen to a response. I am searching for the easiest way to change between commands, to be able to talk as much as possible and to set up a command-tree. I was thinking to do this by keyboard-input, using

> input("Type in function/command name: ")

However, on most of the pages I tried to read up on this everybody says "Yes, it is possible, but a security risk, it's better to avoid it!". This is all well and good, but I want to know: why is this a risk? I thought that the risk is minimized by simply limiting and controlling the possible input by using

> from commandfile import function

in a precise way?

Answer (score 0):

You should validate that the command is one from a specific list of commands you want to allow.  The security risk comes when you `eval` something the user passed in.
Of course, if the allowed commands can do things that are harmful to your system, then that's a risk too.